# Highlight component / area by darkening the rest

Tags: javascript, react-native, libraries

How can I highlight an area/component/element of page by having a hole in a dark overlay using React Native?

[image: desired-output]

While building a set of overlays for how-to use an app (tutorials), I got stuck at a point where I need to implement a vignette component to highlight a specific area.

Ideally I am looking for a solution like [React Native Walkthrough Tooltip](https://github.com/jasongaare/react-native-walkthrough-tooltip) that knows the position of the highlight based on the component. Sadly, this limits me to using only the message box shape.

I already tried 2 different solutions: one based on [React Native MaskedView](https://github.com/react-native-masked-view/masked-view) and another based on [react-native-hole-view](https://github.com/ibitcy/react-native-hole-view#readme). For both I am using [React Native measure](https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation#measurecallback) to get the position of the component that needs highlighting but I am not happy with the result so far.

Any recommendation for how to solve this in React Native?

> Important note: as I am using [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/), on some screens I need to cover the
> header and bottom navigation, this forces me to render my
> HighlightHoleOverlay within a transparent [react native modal](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal).

Answer (score 3):

I've authored a library that I think would fit your needs, you can find it here: [react-native-highlight-overlay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-highlight-overlay).

This library allows you to draw an overlay over the entire screen (or only a specific component) and highlight a single element below the highlight. It's 100% automatic, no manual size calculations required, all you need to do is wrap the component(s) you want to highlight with `HighlightableElement` and give it a unique ID that you then supply to the overlay. Basic example:

```js
import {
    HighlightableElement,
    HighlightableElementProvider,
    HighlightOverlay,
} from "react-native-highlight-overlay";

// Remember to wrap the ROOT of your app in HighlightableElementProvider!
return (
    <HighlightableElementProvider>
        <HighlightableElement id="important_item">
            <TheRestOfTheOwl />
        </HighlightableElement>

        {/* 
          * The HighlightOverlay should be next to the ROOT of the app, 
          * since it is NOT a modal, it's just an absolutely positioned view.
          * If you want it to be a modal, wrap it in <Modal> yourself first,
          * but I recommend not using modals since they can be buggy.
          */}
        <HighlightOverlay
            // You would usually use a state variable for this :)
            // Or store it in a context / store so you can change it from anywhere in the app.
            highlightedElementId="important_item"
            onDismiss={() => {
                // Called when the user clicks outside of the highlighted element.
                // Set "highlightedElementId" to nullish to hide the overlay.
            }}
        />
    </HighlightableElementProvider>
);
```

If you make the highlight `circular` and give it some padding, say `padding: 25`, it should look just like your image.